# Remove consecutive pairs from a list based on a ruleset

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to remove consecutive pairs of cardinal directions from a list if they return to the same position (for example, if we find a 'North' after a 'South', we remove them since they cancel each other out), as part of a bigger function.

I thought of making use of built-in functions for this, but I found out I have no idea how to filter such pairs instead of individual items from a list.

Is there any way to accomplish this via `filter`, `zipWith`, etc?

For example, I tried doing this with zipWith, but it doesn't work since I leave out the right side of the "removed" pair of items. (for example, `removePairs [N,S,E,W]` results in `[S,E]` instead of `[]`)

```
data Dir = N | W | S | E

instance Show (Dir) where
    show (N) = "N"
    show (E) = "E"
    show (W) = "W"
    show (S) = "S"


removePairs :: [Dir] -> [Dir]
removePairs [] = []
removePairs [a] = [a]
removePairs (a:as) = concat(zipWith (removeIfRedundant) (a:as) as)


removeIfRedundant :: Dir -> Dir -> [Dir]
removeIfRedundant (N) (S) = []
removeIfRedundant (S) (N) = []
removeIfRedundant (E) (W) = []
removeIfRedundant (W) (E) = []
removeIfRedundant a b     = [a,b]
```

A normal ruleset would be as follows:

```
isRedundant :: Dir -> Dir -> Bool
isRedundant (N) (S) = True
isRedundant (S) (N) = True
isRedundant (E) (W) = True
isRedundant (W) (E) = True
isRedundant _ _     = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: original way of doing this is kind of silly and excessively iterative. Instead, you can do

```hs
removePairs = foldr combine [] where
   combine x [] = [x]
   combine x (y:ys) = if redundant x y
                      then ys
                      else x : y : ys
```

My original solution is below.

A naive solution would be

```hs
removePairs (x : y : ys) = if isRedundant x y
                           then removePairs ys
                           else x : removePairs (y : ys)
removePairs other = other
```

This doesn't quite work out though - consider `[N, E, W, S]`. We would like to first eliminate `[E, W]` to get `[N, S]` and then additionally eliminate the `[N, S]`.

One nice linear-time way to do this is as follows:

```hs
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy (execState, modify)
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)

type WithStack = State [Dir]

removePairs = reverse . flip execState [] . traverse_ action
   where
      action :: Int -> WithStack ()
      action element = do stack <- get
                          case stack of
                              [] -> push
                              (x:xs) -> if isRedundant x element
                                     then put xs
                                     else push
        where push :: WithStack ()
              push = modify (element:)
```

This will remove all redundancies until none remain.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I was looking for the naive solution, since I felt the problem with not knowing how to do the deletions was...more critical, although my way of repeating the deletions is way more costly (I was rechecking the whole list for redundancies and re-doing the deletions until there were none)...Haskell is quite impressive

Comment: @Lightsong I'm glad I could help. The crazy thing about Haskell is that many of the things one can do in Haskell are possible in any other language. Haskell is powerful because it encourages a powerful pattern of thinking and provides the tools to make this pattern relatively simple.

Comment: Extra fun: can we expand the solution to eliminate things like `[N,E,S,W]` also?

Comment: @luqui What we've really done here is implement the free group on 2 elements (`N` and `E`, for example). We could easily extend this to produce the free group on any number of elements. For example, given a type `T`, we could represent an element of the free group on `T` as a `[(Bool, T)]` with no consecutive elements of the form `(a, True)` and `(a, False)`. We would then define `isRedundant (x, b1) (y, b2) = b1 /= b2 && x == y` and define `removePairs` the same way.

Comment: @MarkSaving It's not obvious to me how to use the fact that we can generalize to the free group on any type to eliminate longer sequences that return to their starting point, as luqui seems to be asking about. Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: @luqui I guess one way would be for the fold to return the position one would need to start at for the whole path to end at (0, 0), together with a `Map` from positions to the reduced string that gets you from that position to (0, 0). I think given those two pieces of information, it shouldn't be too hard to write a function that computes them again for a one-longer sequence, as is needed for `foldr`. The basic idea is to look up the old path, extend it by the current character, then insert that into the `Map` at our new position, but only if that new position isn't already there in the `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off by using fold:

```
removePairs :: [Dir] -> [Dir]
removePairs = foldr op []
    where
        op :: Dir -> [Dir] -> [Dir]
        op S (N:ds) = ds
        op N (S:ds) = ds
        op E (W:ds) = ds
        op W (E:ds) = ds
        op d ds = d:ds
```

This solution folds the list into a new list taking care of the cancellations "as we go".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, folds are the way to go, here is another solution using `foldMap`:

```hs
import Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Foldable

newtype RemRed = RemRed { unRemRed :: Seq Dir }

instance Semigroup RemRed where
  RemRed (xs :|> x) <> RemRed (y :<| ys)
    | isRedundant x y = RemRed xs <> RemRed ys
  RemRed xs <> RemRed ys = RemRed (xs <> ys)

instance Monoid RemRed where
  mempty = RemRed Seq.empty
  mappend = (<>)

removePairs xs = toList (unRemRed (foldMap (RemRed . singleton) xs))
```

Comment: This is definitely a problem related to monoids. In fact, we are trying to represent the group generated by `Dir` with the inverse relations `NS = e` and `EW = e`, and of course groups are also monoids. I definitely like the tail-recursive definition of `<>` that you provided - it's a nice way to solve this problem iteratively and elegantly.